# Attaching onclick attribute to jquery object; $(this) references window object not specific jquery object

Tags: jquery, events, onclick

```
function df(){
 $(this).text('hello world');
}

bn.attr('onclick','df();');
```

My problem is `$(this)` references the jquery `window` object and not the jquery object `bn`.

How do I get a dynamic reference to `bn` in my function `df`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the `onclick` attribute. Use the `.click()` method:

```
bn.click(df);
```

Or the `.on()` method (jQuery 1.7+) or `.bind()` (older versions):

```
bn.on("click", df);
```

Note that there are *no invoking parentheses* after the function identifier. You need to pass a reference to the function, rather than the return value of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
bn.on('click' , df); // Instead of onclick
```

You need to pass in the function pointer rather than function to the DOM for `this` to be in context you expect.